# Laravel loading error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, extension, laravel

When I tried to access my laravel after successfull installation, instead of the default page it shows an error in the webpage.

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I have tried some fixes like this,

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini’: File exists
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Then restart Apache.